# How can I use one index from a data set for two different columns of a different data set without merging twice?

Tags: pandas, merge

I have a bilateral data set which means that I have two columns of country-name.

df:

| Country | Partner Country | year | var1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Turkey | Spain | 2019 | 320 |

df2:

| Country | year | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Turkey | 2019 | 0 |
| Spain | 2019 | 1 |

Desired result:

| Country | index_country | Partner Country | index_partner | Year | var1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Turkey | 0 | Spain | 1 | 2019 | 320 |

I would like to have the desired result without merging twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by unpivot (melt), left join and `pivot`:

```
df = (df1.rename_axis('idx').reset_index()
         .melt(['idx','var1','year'], value_name='Country').merge(df2, how='left')
         .pivot(index=['idx','var1','year'], columns='variable', values=['index','Country'])
           .sort_index(axis=1, level=0, sort_remaining=False)
         )
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' if a == 'index' else b for a, b in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index().drop('idx', axis=1)
print (df)
   var1  year Country Partner Country index_Country index_Partner Country
0   320  2019  Turkey           Spain             0                     1
```

Solution with double `merge`:

```
df = (df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'index':'index_country'}), 
                how='left', 
                on=['Country','year'])
            .merge(df2.rename(columns={'index':'index_partner'}),
                      how='left', left_on=['Partner Country','year'],
                                 right_on=['Country','year'],
                                 suffixes=('','_')).drop('Country_', axis=1)
           )
print (df)
  Country Partner Country  year  var1  index_country  index_partner
0  Turkey           Spain  2019   320              0              1
```

Comment: Many thanks! But one question I have is why do not we use right_on in the first merge.

Comment: @user19562955 - It should be removed, then `merge` check both dataframes and merge by intersection of columns names